iOS Message Filter Extension network action REST calls not authenticated when Shared Web Credentials set
I’ve created a Message Filter Extension using the ILMessageFilterExtension framework, relying on its network action workflow. However, I've encountered an issue where the stored web credentials are not being used in the API calls, despite having set up the associated domains and Apple App Site Association.
enter image description here
I followed the guide provided by Apple here and set up Shared Web Credentials with both webcredential and messagefilter associated domains. Unfortunately, the created and verified credentials are never forwarded to our service with the REST API call.
enter image description here
How can I get the Shared Web Credentials to be applied to the network action workflow in the ILMessageFilterExtension?
We've tried creating a shared web credential for the domain our API exists on, and added the messagefilter & webcredential entitlements.
We expected the Message Filter network action to utilize the same-domain shared web credentials, but the heads don't include any type of auth.

Hello, did you solve this?
